# No longer any appropriate flag for completely off-topic questions

Tags: support, flags

How should we flag questions on Stack Overflow that are not related to programming at all? I cannot find any appropriate flags anymore?

Take this question for instance:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322105/does-anyone-know-where-i-may-get-a-cheap-tooth-removal-in-charlotte-nc

Wouldn't it make sense to have a "not related to programming at all" flag?

Comment: Thanks for that link. It just made my day.

Comment: You mean, off-topic on all SE sites? Because question about comb isn't more off-topic on SO than question about pizza just because programmers eat pizza, but don't use a comb. Either something is off-topic or not. But actually, there's no quick way to close something as off-topic anywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose It does not belong here > Off Topic > Other. That's what folks did in this case, writing a custom message that the question was about Dentists.

I suppose one could argue that it was Spam, but that seems borderline to me.

Comment: It was either a stupid joke, or a spam. Spammer first post such stupid question and then the even more stupid answer with the link to his stupid sell page...